# How to do auto sizing a picturebox within System.Windows.Forms.SplitterPanel in C#

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, controls

I have a .NET PictureBox control added to a Windows.Forms.SplitterPanel.  How do I do auto sizing the PictureBox to fit the SplitterPanel whenever I enlarge or shrink the SplitterPanel with mouse drag.  Following is part of the code I have:

```
PictureBox ScreenPbx = new PictureBox(); 
ScreenPbx.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(480, 360);
ScreenPbx.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
splitContainer.Panel.Controls.Add(ScreenPbx);
```

I have a picture fitted into the PictureBox with StretchImage option but the PictureBox is not "glued" to the splitContainer.panel so when I mouse drag to resize the panel, it doesn't resize the PictureBox within it.  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you are loading an image into the ScreenPbx control.

Instead of setting the size of the PictureBox, try docking it instead:

```
PictureBox ScreenPbx = new PictureBox(); 
ScreenPbx.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
ScreenPbx.SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.StretchImage;
splitContainer.Panel.Controls.Add(ScreenPbx);
```

Alternatively, you could just set the anchors:

```
  pbx.Size = new Size(480, 360);
  pbx.Anchor = AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Top | 
               AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Bottom;
```